# Bash script not returning any values

Tags: bash

```
    #!/bin/bash
    for i in $(ls $1); do
    echo -n $i | sed 's/.dat//g'
    grep '<Overall>' $i | sed 's/<Overall>//g'
    awk 'BEGIN{sum=0} {sum+=$1} END{print sum/NR}'
    sed -re 's/([0-9]+\.[0-9]{2})[0-9]+/\1/g'
    echo 1
    done | sort -nrk2
```

This script should return the average overall rating. I cannot find the mistake, since im not getting any output.

Comment: Not even you `echo 1` gives you any output?  I would be nice for you to provide an example so we can try your script.  Also explain your goal and the expected output.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Well, i have a dat file which my script runs through. This file has tags so the script finds all the lines in which <Overall> is in, deletes it so that the only thing that is left is the integer. Then goes and adds it all, after which it gets devided by the number of <Overall> lines, giving me an average overall rating for the dat file. The script also iterates through the entire dir.

Comment: Ok, so add to your question an example that we can copy to our linux boxes.  then we will run your script, to try to understand what the problem is.  Explain your goal like you would your mother.  Step by step, line per line.  Trust me you will get more answers than "not returning any values"  ;-)

Comment: https://dumptext.com/IpUPLRfN

Comment: I expect something like hotel_856412 2.56

Comment: The `awk` an `sed` commands don't have any input file(s) specified, an therefore will try to read data from the terminal. Are they supposed to be part of a pipeline?

Comment: `echo -n $i | sed 's/.dat//g'` does not modify what the rest of the commands see as the value of `$i`.

Comment: Also, start with shellcheck.net, as `for i in $(ls $1); do` is the wrong way to iterate over a list of file names for multiple reasons.

Comment: Wow, uou really do not want to setup a clear easy to help question...  You start with a `ls $1`.  What are the possible values of $1?  Provide a directory listing of what you expect to come out of `ls $1`.  Then explain each line of code.  What you want it to do, what it does, why you think it's not good.  You see, by explaining your code, you might find the answer, and learn how to debug at the same time.  But for this one,I'm out.

Answer (score 0):

untested:

```
gawk -F'>' '
    BEGINFILE {sum = n = 0}
    $1 == "<Overall" {sum += $2; n++}
    ENDFILE {print FILENAME, (n == 0) ? "n/a" : sum/n}
' *.dat
```